# Python Library for LSM303D 6-Axis Accelerometer / Compass V2.0: unexpected results

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi2

I recently acquired a Grove Sensor board for the LSM303D 6-Axis Accelerometer / Compass. Unfortunately, it transpired that the device did not yet have a Python library (only a [C++ library](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/6Axis_Accelerometer_And_Compass_v2/blob/master/Accelerometer_Compass_LSM303D.cpp) and [Arduino .ino](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/6Axis_Accelerometer_And_Compass_v2/blob/master/examples/Accelerometer_Compass/Accelerometer_Compass.ino) file).

I am attempting to use it with the GrovePi+ board with Raspberry Pi, and would like to use it with Python code, so I made an attempt to transcribe the C++ Code into Python. However, I am getting odd output.

Additional information relating to the device can be found on the [Pololu Datasheet](https://www.pololu.com/file/download/LSM303D.pdf?file_id=0J703)

`sudo i2cdetect -y 1` shows the device can be found at address 0x1E

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- 04 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1e --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Here is the Python Code:

```
#!/usr/bin.env python

import smbus
import time
import math
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import struct

rev = GPIO.RPI_REVISION
if rev == 2 or rev == 3:
    bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
else:
    bus = smbus.SMBus(0)

### LSM303 Address ###
LSM303D_ADDR    = 0x1E # Assuming SA0 grounded

### LSM303 Register definitions ###
TEMP_OUT_L      = 0x05
TEMP_OUT_H      = 0x06
STATUS_REG_M    = 0x07
OUT_X_L_M       = 0x08
OUT_X_H_M       = 0x09
OUT_Y_L_M       = 0x0A
OUT_Y_H_M       = 0x0B
OUT_Z_L_M       = 0x0C
OUT_Z_H_M       = 0x0D
WHO_AM_I        = 0x0F
INT_CTRL_M      = 0x12
INT_SRC_M       = 0x13
INT_THS_L_M     = 0x14
INT_THS_H_M     = 0x15
OFFSET_X_L_M    = 0x16
OFFSET_X_H_M    = 0x17
OFFSET_Y_L_M    = 0x18
OFFSET_Y_H_M    = 0x19
OFFSET_Z_L_M    = 0x1A
OFFSET_Z_H_M    = 0x1B
REFERENCE_X     = 0x1C
REFERENCE_Y     = 0x1D
REFERENCE_Z     = 0x1E
CTRL_REG0       = 0x1F
CTRL_REG1       = 0x20
CTRL_REG2       = 0x21
CTRL_REG3       = 0x22
CTRL_REG4       = 0x23
CTRL_REG5       = 0x24
CTRL_REG6       = 0x25
CTRL_REG7       = 0x26
STATUS_REG_A    = 0x27
OUT_X_L_A       = 0x28
OUT_X_H_A       = 0x29
OUT_Y_L_A       = 0x2A
OUT_Y_H_A       = 0x2B
OUT_Z_L_A       = 0x2C
OUT_Z_H_A       = 0x2D
FIFO_CTRL       = 0x2E
FIFO_SRC        = 0x2F
IG_CFG1         = 0x30
IG_SRC1         = 0x31
IG_THS1         = 0x32
IG_DUR1         = 0x33
IG_CFG2         = 0x34
IG_SRC2         = 0x35
IG_THS2         = 0x36
IG_DUR2         = 0x37
CLICK_CFG       = 0x38
CLICK_SRC       = 0x39
CLICK_THS       = 0x3A
TIME_LIMIT      = 0x3B
TIME_LATENCY    = 0x3C
TIME_WINDOW     = 0x3D
ACT_THS         = 0x3E
ACT_DUR         = 0x3F

### Mag scales ###
MAG_SCALE_2     = 0x00 # full-scale is +/- 2 Gauss
MAG_SCALE_4     = 0x20 # +/- 4 Guass
MAG_SCALE_8     = 0x40 # +/- 8 Guass
MAG_SCALE_12    = 0x60 # +/- 12 Guass

ACCEL_SCALE     = 2 # +/- 2g

X = 0
Y = 1
Z = 2

def twos_comp(val, bits):
    # Calculate the 2s complement of int:val #
    if(val&(1<<(bits-1)) != 0):
        val = val - (1<<bits)
    return val
#   return val if val < 32768 else val - 65536

class accelcomp:
    mag = [0,0,0]
    accel = [0,0,0]
    tiltcomp = [0,0,0]
    heading=0
    headingDegrees=0
    tiltHeading=0
    tiltHeadingDegrees=0

    def __init__(self):
        whoami = bus.read_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, WHO_AM_I)

        if(whoami == 0x49):
            bus.write_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, CTRL_REG1, 0x57) # 0x57 = ODR=50hz, all accel axes on ## maybe 0x27 is Low Res?
            bus.write_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, CTRL_REG2, (3<<6)|(0<<3)) # set full scale +/- 2g
            bus.write_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, CTRL_REG3, 0x00) # no interrupt
            bus.write_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, CTRL_REG4, 0x00) # no interrupt
            bus.write_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, CTRL_REG5, (4<<2)) # 0x10 = mag 50Hz output rate
            bus.write_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, CTRL_REG6, MAG_SCALE_2) # Magnetic Scale +/1 1.3 Guass
            bus.write_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, CTRL_REG7, 0x00) # 0x00 continuous conversion mode

    def getMag(self):
        self.mag[X] = twos_comp(bus.read_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, OUT_X_H_M) << 8 | 
                          bus.read_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, OUT_X_L_M), 16)
        self.mag[Y] = twos_comp(bus.read_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, OUT_Y_H_M) << 8 | 
                          bus.read_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, OUT_Y_L_M), 16)
        self.mag[Z] = twos_comp(bus.read_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, OUT_Z_H_M) << 8 | 
                          bus.read_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, OUT_Z_L_M), 16)

    def getAccel(self):
        accel = [0,0,0]
        accel[X] = twos_comp(bus.read_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, OUT_X_H_A) << 8 | 
                           bus.read_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, OUT_X_L_A), 16)
        accel[Y] = twos_comp(bus.read_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, OUT_Y_H_A) << 8 | 
                           bus.read_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, OUT_Y_L_A), 16)
        accel[Z] = twos_comp(bus.read_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, OUT_Z_H_A) << 8 | 
                           bus.read_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, OUT_Z_L_A), 16)

        for i in range(X, Z+1):
            self.accel[i] = accel[i] / math.pow(2, 15) * ACCEL_SCALE

    def getHeading(self):
        self.heading = math.atan2(self.mag[X], self.mag[Y])

        if self.heading < 0:
            self.heading += 2*math.pi
        if self.heading > 2*math.pi:
            self.heading -= 2*math.pi

        self.headingDegrees = round(math.degrees(self.heading),2)

    def getTiltHeading(self):
        truncate = [0,0,0]
        for i in range(X, Z+1):
            truncate[i] = math.copysign(min(math.fabs(self.accel[i]), 1.0), self.accel[i])
        try:
            pitch = math.asin(-1*truncate[X])
            roll = math.asin(truncate[Y]/math.cos(pitch)) if abs(math.cos(pitch)) >= abs(truncate[Y]) else 0
            # set roll to zero if pitch approaches -1 or 1

            self.tiltcomp[X] = self.mag[X] * math.cos(pitch) + self.mag[Z] * math.sin(pitch)
            self.tiltcomp[Y] = self.mag[X] * math.sin(roll) * math.sin(pitch) + \
                               self.mag[Y] * math.cos(roll) - self.mag[Z] * math.sin(roll) * math.cos(pitch)
            self.tiltcomp[Z] = self.mag[X] * math.cos(roll) * math.sin(pitch) + \
                               self.mag[Y] * math.sin(roll) + \
                               self.mag[Z] * math.cos(roll) * math.cos(pitch)
            self.tiltHeading = math.atan2(self.tiltcomp[Y], self.tiltcomp[X])

            if self.tiltHeading < 0:
                self.tiltHeading += 2*math.pi
            if self.tiltHeading > 2*math.pi:
                self.heading -= 2*math.pi

            self.tiltHeadingDegrees = round(math.degrees(self.tiltHeading),2)

        except Exception:
            print "AccelX {}, AccelY {}".format(self.accel[X], self.accel[Y])
            print "TruncX {}, TruncY {}".format(truncate[X], truncate[Y])
            print "Pitch {}, cos(pitch) {}, Bool(cos(pitch)) {}".format(pitch, math.cos(pitch), bool(math.cos(pitch)))


    def isMagReady(self):
        temp =  bus.read_byte_data(LSM303D_ADDR, STATUS_REG_M) & 0x03

        return temp

    def update(self):

        self.getAccel()
        self.getMag()
        self.getHeading()
        self.getTiltHeading()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    from time import sleep

    lsm = accelcomp()

    print '     Accelerometer     ||        Compass        ||              Heading'
    print '   x   |   y   |   z   ||   x   |   y   |   z   ||       calc      | tilt corrected  |'
    while True:
        lsm.getAccel()
        while not bool(lsm.isMagReady()):
            print "Not Ready!"
            sleep(.01)
        lsm.getMag()
        lsm.getHeading()
        lsm.getTiltHeading()
        print '{0:.3f} |{1:.3f} |{2:.3f} ||{3:6} |{4:6} |{5:6} ||  {6:6} deg     |  {7:6} deg     |'.format(
                    lsm.accel[X], lsm.accel[Y], lsm.accel[Z], lsm.mag[X], lsm.mag[Y], lsm.mag[Z], lsm.headingDegrees, lsm.tiltHeadingDegrees)
        sleep(.5)
```

Some sample output:

```
    Accelerometer     ||        Compass        ||              Heading
  x   |   y   |   z   ||   x   |   y   |   z   ||       calc      | tilt corrected  |
0.022 |-0.012 |1.056 ||   876 | -1119 |  5788 ||  141.94 deg     |  305.58 deg     |
0.027 |-0.011 |1.052 ||   919 | -1128 |  5826 ||  140.83 deg     |  305.62 deg     |
0.026 |-0.010 |1.053 ||   903 | -1108 |  5777 ||  140.82 deg     |  305.61 deg     |
0.024 |-0.009 |1.054 ||   914 | -1140 |  5790 ||  141.28 deg     |  305.57 deg     |
0.024 |-0.010 |1.056 ||   895 | -1122 |  5801 ||  141.42 deg     |  305.42 deg     |
0.024 |-0.010 |1.055 ||   905 | -1088 |  5747 ||  140.25 deg     |  306.69 deg     |
0.022 |-0.008 |1.057 ||   900 | -1106 |  5748 ||  140.86 deg     |  306.15 deg     |
```

One point that is obvious from the output displayed is that the acceleration in the Z direction is, sitting on the table, greater than 1g. It's close enough to be considered ok, although when tilted, both X and Y also go over 1g, which throws Math Errors with the asin function in getTiltHeading(), hence the truncation.

However, the real issue is with errors in the compass over a full rotation. I aligned the device north relative to the compass on my phone, and it gave a close value to 360 / 0 degrees. However, rotating it clockwise around the circle introduced errors that climbed up to about 30 degrees off the expected value around 255 degrees (near magnetic West).

Tabulated Experiment:

```
Angle   Trial 1 Trial 2 Trial 3 Trial 4 AVERAGE  ERROR
0       356.53  355.18  355.74  357.13  356.145  356.145
0       -3.47   -4.82   -4.26   -2.87   -3.855   -3.855
15      11.26   10.65   11.57   11.02   11.125   -3.875
30      30.29   30.82   30.74   30.29   30.535   0.535
45      40.24   40.32   39.95   39.93   40.11    -4.89
60      55.84   55.51   55.53   54.89   55.4425  -4.5575
75      67.23   67.42   68.46   68.23   67.835   -7.165
90      83.65   83.8    83.96   83.55   83.74    -6.26
105     101.11  100.91  100.13  100.66  100.7025 -4.2975
120     117.15  117.13  116.59  115.79  116.665  -3.335
135     125.92  125.56  125.19  126.14  125.702  -9.2975
150     142.74  142.44  142.94  142.56  142.67   -7.33
165     157.22  156.77  157.53  157.07  157.1475 -7.8525
180     171.97  171.61  172.17  172.26  172.0025 -7.9975
195     183.81  183.47  182.99  183.39  183.415  -11.585
210     195.59  196.6   197.2   197.58  196.7425 -13.2575
225     210.07  210.59  209.47  210.21  210.085  -14.915
240     218.97  219.3   219.53  219.48  219.32   -20.68
255     226.13  226.27  226.61  226.18  226.2975 -28.7025
270     242.63  241.64  242.33  242.32  242.23   -27.77
285     259.89  258.83  258.92  259     259.16   -25.84
300     283.8   284.51  283.51  282.87  283.6725 -16.3275
315     294.05  295.47  295.23  295.57  295.08   -19.92
330     320.09  319.28  318.64  318.16  319.0425 -10.9575
345     342.39  342.87  342.34  343.13  342.6825 -2.3175
360     8.85    8.48    8.93    9.1     8.84     8.84
```

Graph of errors:

[image: Error over Angle: deviation from expected angle]

Is there some error I've made in the library, or might I be dealing with a faulty device?

(The dotted trendline is a 6th-order polynomial, to which I doubt indicates any actual relation. After all, I would expect this function to be cyclic.)

Comment: Did you have any electrical equipment on during the test? When you oriented the board at 255 degrees did that put it closer to metallic/electical stuff? I've not looked through your code very closely, but nothing obvious leaps out to me, could it just be that your sensor is a bit too sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

Just a little late to the party ;p

In your `getTiltHeading` function, this line:

```
self.heading -= 2*math.pi
```

might need to be:

```
self.tiltHeading -= 2*math.pi
```